# passing javascript variable in app.settings (client side variable to server side)

Tags: javascript, asp.net

> I want to read the config file in javascript that is the google key
>   value. here what i am trying to do is passing a javascript
>   variable"keyvalue" that is the keyname in config file but it does not
>   work. i just want it so that the js function automatically picks up
>   the google key according to site URL whether it may be test or dev or
>   qa.abc.com can anyone help me what should i do to read the value form
>   config file.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

function ReadConfigSettings()
{ 

var url="test.abc.com"; //window.location.href

var patharray= new Array();

patharray =url.split('.');

var first = patharray[0];

 var keyvalue="GoogleKey_"+ first;

 var key='<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[keyvalue]%>';

 alert(key);
}

 </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="ReadConfigSettings()" />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

> my config file

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="GoogleKey_dev" value="ABQIAAAAJ4psDZ8kCtN062-LDcwiXhQ85a215fgrIsfghh547457h1ETJRYlwaBGrrytgytg56g7Mx4QFQ"/>
    <add key="GoogleKey_qa" value="ABQIAAAACoUjxmFCsPtytryhtyty547547Ryt5gVV28BYSHIaU0BRwPyLrf_gf546Jd_5qxcNZ-_b7WZw"/>
    <add key="GoogleKey_test" value="AIzaSyvbghgfyh54654650x2SlGb33KrTtIBc"/>
```

Comment: [Read Configuration Settings of Web.config using Javascript](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/77917/Read-Configuration-Settings-of-Web-config-using-Ja)

Comment: thanks for your answer but i want to pass a js variable in ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Setting"] so simply i want is ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["my js variable"] and my js variable holds my key name.

Answer (score 1):

Web.Config

```
</configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="Setting" value="Value"/>
    <appSettings>
</configuration>
```

In Aspx page take

```
<asp:HiddenField runat='server' id='hidkey' />
```

In javascript

```
 document.getElementById('<%=hidkey.ClientID %>').value = '<%=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Setting"] %>';
```

Now access in C#

```
  string key=hidkey.value;//Here u get web.config [Setting] value
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i want to pass a js variable in ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Setting"] so simply i want is ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["my js variable"] and my js variable holds my key name.

Comment: not possible...because AppSettings["Setting"] extract from web.config file.

Comment: yes as you can see above in js i wrote var keyvalue="GoogleKey_"+ first; so i want to pass this variable in AppSettings[] so that it automatically picks up the value from webconfig as per the parameter such as GoogleKey_test or GoogleKey_dev etc

Comment: then take it in hiddenfield and acess on code behind(server side) its simple

Answer (score 0):

You Can't Mix server side with client side, like this. you need to use AJAX for this kind of functionality